# Testing constraints that use impact() instead of reward() or penalize()

Tags: java, unit-testing, optaplanner

I have a constraint that uses `impactConfigurable`, but the `SingleConstraintAssertion` interface only supports testing if a constraint rewards or penalises. For example, I cannot do the following:

```
constraintVerifier.verifyThat(myConstraint).given(obj1, obj2).impactsBy(1);
```

or

```
constraintVerifier.verifyThat(myConstraint).given(obj1, obj2).impactsBy(-1);
```

Is there a way around this?

I am using OptaPlanner version 8.25.0.Final.

Answer (score 1):

That is by design. Regardless of whether your constraint does penalize, reward or impact, the end result still is either a penalty or a reward. Therefore in your tests, you are expected to specify the expected outcome. For example, if you expect a negative impact, you are, in fact, expecting a penalty:

```
constraintVerifier.verifyThat(myConstraint).given(obj1, obj2).penalizesBy(1);
```

As a side note: we are really curious what constraints in the real world actually require the use of `impact()` instead of `penalize()` or `reward()`. We were not able to think of any realistic constraint that would be positive and negative at the same time.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to describe my use case and examples in such a small comments box, so is there somewhere I can write this up and send you my reasons? Anyway, regardless of whether I am doing the right thing or not (my constraint works perfectly), how can I test this?

Comment: I have slightly modified the answer. For sharing more complex pieces of code or text, you can use chat if you like: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/; or Github Gist; or Pastebin. Options are plenty.

Comment: Unfortunately using the example above does not work. If I positively impact the score and test for a reward, I get the following error message:

`Broken expectation.
        Constraint: com.myconstraints.../My Constraint
   Expected reward: 4 (class java.lang.Integer)
     Actual impact: 4 (class java.lang.Integer)

  Explanation of score (0hard/0medium/4soft):
    Constraint match totals:
        4soft: constraint (My Constraint) has 1 matches:
            4soft: justifications ([2])`

Comment: I'd consider that a bug.

Comment: In fact using this approach I am able to test: https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#constraintStreamsTestingAllConstraints

Comment: Where should I raise the bug?

Comment: https://issues.redhat.com/projects/PLANNER, thank you.